# Formatting date and time: in view (template) or in controller?

Tags: django, datetime, laravel, model-view-controller, web-frameworks

Suppose I try to adhere to MVC pattern. Suppose the project may or may not require internationalization.

Where is a better place to format date and time to desired representation - in controller or in a template, or maybe in model? What is a common practice in popular web frameworks, e.g. Django or Laravel?

Comment: Views are not templates. Output formatting is part of shared UI logic and should be contained in [presentation objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

Comment: @tereško Can you be more specific, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Which part confused you?

Comment: @tereško If views are not templates, what are they?

Comment: @tereško By the way, you somehow managed to lure me into some fruitful discussion, without actually answering my simple question about proper place for date formatting in web frameworks. Amazing :(

Comment: I answered. And the answer was "in presentation objects".

Answer (score 1):

In django the proper place is in the django template (mvc view).

- you can either use the builtin date formatting tags
- or create your own custom date formating tags
- or create a method on your model that returns the date formatted in
- or change the global localization settings for how dates and times should be displayed.